# Monitoring HBase Cluster

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera, opentsdb

I found out that Hbase provides various metrics which could be used to monitor the cluster and tune the configuration parameters for best performance. So can someone tell what does these metrics means and what are the most important metrics to consider?

Comment: The answer depends on the number of region servers in your HBase cluster. The list of key metrics to watch for 5-node cluster is different from a scale-out installation.

Comment: Can you provide some example of what metrics to watch for 5-node cluster?

Answer (score 1):

**`Metric Name`** **`Explanation of value`**

```
hbase.regionserver.blockCacheCount
```

Block cache item count in memory. This is the number of blocks of StoreFiles (HFiles) in the cache.

```
hbase.regionserver.blockCacheEvictedCount
```

Number of blocks that had to be evicted from the block cache due to heap size
constraints.

```
hbase.regionserver.blockCacheFree
```

Block cache memory available (bytes).

```
hbase.regionserver.blockCacheHitCachingRatio
```

Block cache hit caching ratio (0 to 100). The cache-hit ratio for reads configured to look in the cache (i.e., cacheBlocks=true).

```
hbase.regionserver.blockCacheHitCount
```

Number of blocks of StoreFiles (HFiles) read from the cache.

```
hbase.regionserver.blockCa
cheHitRatio
```

Block cache hit ratio (0 to 100). Includes all read requests, although those with cacheBlocks=false will always read from disk and be counted as a “cache miss.”

```
hbase.regionserver.blockCacheMissCount
```

Number of blocks of StoreFiles (HFiles) requested but not read from the cache.

```
hbase.regionserver.blockCacheSize
```

Block cache size in memory (bytes), that is, memory in use by the BlockCache.

```
hbase.regionserver.compactionQueueSize
```

Size of the compaction queue. This is the number of Stores in the RegionServer that have been targeted for compaction.

```
hbase.regionserver.flushQueueSize
```

Number of enqueued regions in the MemStore awaiting flush.

```
hbase.regionserver.fsReadLatency_avg_time
```

Filesystem read latency (ms). This is the average time to read from HDFS.

```
hbase.regionserver.fsReadLatency_num_ops
```

Filesystem read operations.

```
hbase.regionserver.memstoreSizeMB
```

Sum of all the memstore sizes in this RegionServer (MB).
`hbase.regionserver.regions` Number of regions served by the RegionServer.

```
hbase.regionserver.requests
```

Total number of read and write requests. Requests correspond to RegionServer RPC
calls; thus, a single Get will result in 1 request, but a Scan with caching set to 1,000

**All these metrics have their own significance you can decide on your own after reading above given description of each metric.**